# How to open NavigationDrawer with Fab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I want while click on FAB button it Open Navigation Drawer.

How to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at this [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View))

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.myFAB); 
myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
       //if you need open the slide:
       mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

       //if you need close the slide
       mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);  
    } 
});
```

Comment: but what to do when fab is hidden under drawer and you slide back to close it ??

` FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                    //if you need close the slide
                    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

                }
                counter++;
            }
        });
`

Answer (score 1):

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

and add following line in Fab Onclick

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```